# MovingMap maps to second level unexpectedly

Tags: list-manipulation, curated-data, map, time-series, finance

I'm trying to build a financial indicator in mathematica. I import some historical data

```
 Data = FinancialData["^GSPC", "OHLCV", {2009}];
 Data[[1;;5]]

 {{{2009, 1, 2}, {902.99, 934.73, 899.35, 931.8, 4048270000}}, 
  {{2009, 1, 5}, {929.17, 936.63, 919.53, 927.45, 5413910000}}, 
  {{2009, 1, 6}, {931.17, 943.85, 927.28, 934.7, 5392620000}}, 
  {{2009, 1, 7}, {927.45, 927.45, 902.37, 906.65, 4704940000}}, 
  {{2009, 1, 8}, {905.73, 910., 896.81, 909.73, 4991550000}}}
```

Now I want to apply a function to a moving window of the data:

```
 MovingMap[foo[#] &, Data, 5]
```

However, MovingMap does something unexpected it maps over the second entry in each list:

```
{{3440361600, 
  foo[{{902.99, 934.73, 899.35, 931.8, 4048270000}, 
       {929.17, 936.63, 919.53, 927.45, 5413910000}, 
       {931.17, 943.85, 927.28, 934.7, 5392620000}, 
       {927.45, 927.45, 902.37, 906.65, 4704940000}, 
       {905.73, 910., 896.81, 909.73, 4991550000}}]},
       {3440448000, 
       foo[{{929.17, 936.63, 919.53, 927.45, 5413910000}, 
            {931.17, 943.85, 927.28, 934.7, 5392620000}, 
            {927.45, 927.45, 902.37, 906.65, 4704940000}, 
            {905.73, 910., 896.81, 909.73, 4991550000}, 
            {909.91, 911.93, 888.31, 890.35, 4716500000}}]}, ...}
```

I was expecting something like a moving window through the list:

```
  foo[{{{date}, {O, H, L, C, V}},
       {{date}, {O, H, L, C, V}},
       {{date}, {O, H, L, C, V}},
       {{date}, {O, H, L, C, V}}, ...}]
```

What have I misunderstood or done wrong here?

Just to be thorough

```
 MovingMap[foo &, dowData[[1 ;; 200]], {20, "Day"}]
```

Produces this output:

```
{{3441484800, foo}, 
 {3441571200, foo}, 
 {3441657600, foo},...}
```

EDIT: It seems when given a time series like that which FinancialData returns
MovingMap will Map over the data for you. Removing the need to deal with the dates yourself. Poorly documented, but convenient if you know about this behaviour.

However, my indicator is calling FinancialIndicator itself, which seems to need the full date/OHLCV time series. Is there any way to have this work as one might expect?

Example of what I'm trying to do:

```
 intraTotal[ts_] := Total[FinancialIndicator["TrueRange" ][ts]];

 periodRange[ts_] := Max[Map[ #[[2, 2]] &, ts]] - Min[Map[ #[[2, 3]] &, ts]];

 FracDim[ts_, period_] := intraTotal[Take[ts, -period]]/periodRange[Take[ts, -period]];
```

Comment: `MovingMap[foo, Data, {5, "Day"}]`

Comment: Still shows the same behaviour.

Comment: You can just rewrite your `FracDim` to work similar to the `FinancialIndicator`s. Something like `fracDim[ts_, period_] := Table[
   intraTotal[ts[[s ;; s + period]]]/
   periodRange[ts[[s ;; s + period]]],
   {s, Length@ts - period}];`.

Comment: That would work in the small. But it stops me from writing indicators which rely on other indicators to do part of the work. and this seems like exactly the sort of use case MovingMap was designed for.

Answer (score 6):

`MovingMap` is doing, what it is supposed to do.
Evaluating

```
AbsoluteTime /@ (Data[[1 ;; 5]][[All, 1]])
```

> `{3439843200, 3440102400, 3440188800, 3440275200, 3440361600}`

gives the timestamps for the first five data points in absolute time.
The output of

```
MovingMap[foo[#] &, Data, 5]
```

or simpler

```
MovingMap[foo[#] &, Data[[1 ;; 5]], 5]
```

> ```
> {{3440361600, 
>   foo[{{902.99, 934.73, 899.35, 931.8, 4048270000}, 
>        {929.17, 936.63, 919.53, 927.45, 5413910000}, 
>        {931.17, 943.85, 927.28, 934.7, 5392620000}, 
>        {927.45, 927.45, 902.37, 906.65, 4704940000}, 
>        {905.73, 910., 896.81, 909.73, 4991550000}}]}}
> ```

shows that `foo` is applied to the values of the first five data points and gets combined with the timestamps of the fifth data point.

---

### How to make a `FinancialIndicator` work within `MovingMap`

I didn't test all, but it seems like no `FinancialIndicator` is actually using the timestamps and I can't see a reason why any should. Therefore you only need to create the expected input structure.
For your example:

```
intraTotal[ts_] := 
 Total[FinancialIndicator["TrueRange"][Transpose[{ConstantArray[{}, Length@ts], ts}]]]
```

Now

```
MovingMap[intraTotal[#] &, data, 5]
```

will work as you had expected.

Comment: Yeah, that's it

Comment: Okay, the documentation isn't clear on this then. You're right that it IS mentioned that it understands time series, but only much farther down the page. Passing in these naked OHLCV lists causes problems using FinancialIndicator within the functions.

Comment: @Steven Most `FinancialIndicator`s have time frame as a parameter (most with a default value) and already do some kind of moving mapping. Therefore they don't seem to be build to work together with `MovingMap`.

Comment: I understand that, I'm using a FinancialIndicator inside of my own indicator which I'd be using MovingMap to calculate. So moving MovingMap is losing me information that FinancialIndicator needs.

Comment: @Steven To the end of my answer I added a way how you can make `FinancialIndicator` work together with `MovingMap`. Does this solve your problems?

Comment: @Steven The other two functions in your example probably should be `periodRange[ts_] := Max[ts[[All, 2]]] - Min[ts[[All, 3]]]` and `fracDim[ts_] := intraTotal[ts]/periodRange[ts]`.

Comment: Karsten that solves the problem nicely. Thanks! Though Wolfram probably want to either update moving map or make things clear farther up in the documentation.